# Simple Implementation of the AD9834 DDS Chip

Tags: spi, dds

I'd like to see a simple implementation of the [AD9834 DDS chip](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9834.pdf). I'd like to use this in a homebrew Amateur Radio build.

The test circuits in the datasheet were rather confusing, and the implementations in other radio schematics had a lot of extra stuff connected.

Basically, I simply want SPI and a 50MHz clock in, and then get the variable sine wave out.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The datasheet usually is _the_ place for questions like this. Why not ask us what you do not understand in the datasheet?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the simplest, and easiest to understand, implementation of the AD9834 is Analog's early evaluation board for it, the [EVAL-AD9834EBZ](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/eval_boards/137452056EVAL_AD9834EB.pdf).

Figure 5 on page 8 of the documentation linked above is the schematic, easy to understand, well segmented, thus easy to decompose into your specific requirement subset.
[image: Schematic]

Figure 16 of the [User Guide for EVAL-AD9834SDZ](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/user_guides/UG-266.pdf) (a newer board) contains a different schematic variant.

These user guides also have PCB artwork, but that is best redeveloped afresh after reducing the schematic to the minimum needed.

---

The older evaluation boards are available on eBay for as little as $50, compared to ~$100 for the current versions, **in case your purpose is evaluation rather than production**.

Comment: Oh! That's much simpler! Thanks! Also, my 50 MHz can oscillator is creating a sine wave. Can I use that to drive the MCLK line? Or will that screw everything up?

And, thanks for helping a noob. :)

Comment: @MarkBaldridge The sine wave should work fine as clock source. You're welcome. :-)